# Need solution for "Notice: Undefined index: submit in in PHP $_POST['submit']"

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post, php-5.5

**I've this `HTML` code for posting a `form` data to the `database`:**

```
`  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="createform">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <textarea name="address" id="address" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <textarea name="contact" id="contact" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Contacts"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contactemail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="email" name="emailcontact" class="form-control" id="contactemail" placeholder="Email">`enter code here`
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create" name="save"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>`
```

**`PHP` Code for this `HTML Form` below:**

```
` if($_POST['save'] == "Create"){
        $current_user = intval($_SESSION['id']);
        $query = "insert into addresses(name,address,contact,emailcontact,user_id) values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['contact']."','".$_POST['emailcontact']."','".$current_user."')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        header("Location: addressbook.php");
    }`
```

My Problem is Whenever i'm trying to `Post` the form with data by clicking the `Create` button, This below `warning` is showing in my `web page`:

```
`Notice: Undefined index: save in C:\xampp\htdocs\working_files\Online_Address_Book_PHP\php\utility.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: delete in C:\xampp\htdocs\working_files\Online_Address_Book_PHP\php\utility.php on line 21
`
```

In my site there is many `$_POST['--']` data. and for `all of them` my `browser` is showing this `warning messages`. How can i overcome this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Wow*! I've solved this problem by my own. Just use this `code` before every `check`:**

```
`if(isset($_POST['save'])){
.......
}`
```

**MY code solution is this below:**

```
`if(isset($_POST['save'])){
if($_POST['save'] == "Create"){
        $current_user = intval($_SESSION['id']);
        $query = "insert into addresses(name,address,contact,emailcontact,user_id) values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['contact']."','".$_POST['emailcontact']."','".$current_user."')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        header("Location: addressbook.php");
    }
}`
```